# Can we get inline retagging for questions in review & mod tools routes?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, moderator-tools, inline-tag-editor

The inline retagging link in /review routes seem to be missing. Can we please add this?

A moderator in the comments lets us know that this is also missing from the mod tools.

[image: Picture of a question in /review that needs more tags, but there's no inline retagging.]

Comment: I think that's more of a [feature-request] than a [bug]. (The difference being that if it's a [bug] the answer is "caching", but if it's a [feature-request] then "6 to 8 weeks")

Comment: I don't consider missing features bugs (especially minor features), if the feature was there but didn't work as expected it would be a bug. However my comment was extremely light hearted, and my definition of what a bug is changes every time someone discovers a bug in my code, so... ;P

Comment: Moderator tools as well please.

Comment: Ditto for the new First Posts review page.

Answer (score 1):

This entire UI is gone, so I'm declining this. It might make sense in *some* of the new review queues ([First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171625/edit-tags-button-missing-in-first-post-queue)), but is likely irrelevant for most of them.