# "Edit tags" button missing in first post queue

Tags: feature-request, tags, review

One of the most common things that needs to be done in the first post queue is retagging.

However, the 10k/mod inline "edit tags" option(which is quite useful, IMO) doesn't seem to be there for this queue.

[image]

Could this feature be added to the queue?

Comment: +1, very important indeed!

Comment: I don't like this. It's true that retagging is very commonly needed on first posts, but you can retag by editing, like any normal 10K- user would do. And hopefully, you'll also fix everything else that might need fixing with the post. Given all the troubles we've been having with robo-reviewers, I don't want to encourage lazy retag-only edits via review.