# Review questions are missing "edit tags" button

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, review

I was reviewing First Posts on Astronomy SE and noticed that the "Edit tags" button was missing. As I have access to the moderator tools, which include an Edit Tags feature, I was a little surprised that the functionality wasn't there for the Review Queues. Is this intentional?

**Note:** This is not a duplicate of [Can we get inline retagging for questions in review & mod tools routes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196390/878398) because it refers to an outdated system used by SE. As @RyanM says:

> That declined feature request refers to an old UI and the answer features a passing remark by Shog that it might make sense for First Posts. It wouldn't be a good duplicate for this question, even though Shog's remark is related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we get inline retagging for questions in review & mod tools routes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196390/282094)

Comment: That declined feature request refers to an old UI and the answer features a passing remark by Shog that it might make sense for First Posts. It wouldn't be a good duplicate for this question, even though Shog's remark is related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In First Posts, each post only gets one review, so you're generally trying to fix *everything* that's wrong with a post.  While it's certainly possible that the only thing wrong is that it's mistagged, my experience is that there's usually something else that could use a touch-up while you're there.

Bringing up the full editor encourages fixing up the rest of the post while you're at it, and if it really does just need a retag, it's still easy enough to scroll down to the tags, fix them, and hit enter—the edit summary will be automatically populated as though you'd edited it from the tag editor.